# Alamofire request issue while using header

Tags: ios, swift3, alamofire

I am trying to make post request and also sending header token but it is alway giving me error. Error is "Extra argument 'method' in call". I tried many ways to fix this but not succeed.

```
func eventsDate(){
    let postData = ["month":12,
        "year": 2017]
    let headerToken = defaultObject.object(forKey: KHeaderToken)
    let headers = ["Authorization": headerToken]
    Alamofire.request(KCalendarUrl, method: .post, parameters: postData, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers).responseJSON(completionHandler: { response in
                        print(response)
                        //to get status code
                        if let status = response.response?.statusCode {
                            switch(status){
                            case 200:
                                print("example success")
                                if let result = response.result.value {
                                    let JSON = result as! NSDictionary
                                }


                            default:
                                print("error with response status: \(status)")


                            }
                        }
                        //to get JSON return value

                })
 }
```

Comment: let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
        "Authorization": headerToken!,
        "Accept": "application/json"
    ]  Use Like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The headers are supposed to be of type HTTPHeaders which in turn is [String:String]. 
The only issue that i can  think of which is happening here is that headerToken is not of String type. 
Use

```
let headerToken = defaultObject.object(forKey: KHeaderToken) as! String
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure you are conforming to the types required by the `request` function. In your case, you should make sure:

- `KCalendarUrl` is URLConvertible => It can be either a `String` / `URL` / URLComponents / URLRequest (unless you use extensions / custom types conforming to URLConvertible)
- `headerToken` is a String (`headers` must be a Dictionary of both String keys and values)